# Javascript merge and rename Json objects

Tags: javascript, json

Simple problem here: 2 Json objects I would like to merge, while renaming the second.

First Array (obj1):

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Metric 1",
      "value":33731487,
   },
   {  
      "name":"Metric 2",
      "value":11252893,
   }
]
```

Second Array (obj2):

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Metric 1",
      "value":118181851,
   },
   {  
      "name":"Metric 2",
      "value":15151,
   }
]
```

Desired Result:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Metric 1", // Obj1
      "value":118181851, // Obj1
      "name_compare":"Metric 1", // Obj2
      "value_compare":148748, // Obj2
   },
   {  
      "name":"Metric 2", // Obj1
      "value":15151, // Obj1
      "name_compare":"Metric 2", // Obj2
      "value_compare":741178, // Obj2
   }
]
```

So I tried:

Renaming the Obj2 (works ok):

```
function JsonRename(obj) {
    var output = {};
    for (i in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj[i]) === '[object Object]') {
            output[i] = JsonRename(obj[i]);
        } else {
            output[i+'_compare'] = obj[i];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

I've then tried to merge them by using:

```
function JsonMergeCompare(obj1, obj2 ) {

  var renamed_obj2 = JsonRename(obj2);

  var output = {};
  for (i in obj1) {

    output[i] = obj1[i];
    output[i] = renamed_obj2[i];

  }

  return output;

}
```

My problem is most certainly in the function above, because it only returns the obj2 (which makes sense as I'm iterating over output[i] twice) but how can I get in and change only the key -> values?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or plunkr?

Comment: Why the -1? I think it's a fairly decent question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to define an Array.zip() function like this:

```
Array.zip = function(left, right, combinerFunction) {
    var counter, results = [];

    for(counter = 0; counter < Math.min(left.length, right.length); counter++) {
        results.push(combinerFunction(left[counter], right[counter]));
    }

    return results;
};
```

And then use it to zip the arrays together like this:

```
var resultArray = Array.zip(array1, array2, function(one, two) {
    return {
        name: one.name, 
        value: one.value,
        name_compare: two.name, 
        value_compare: two.value
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say the function is the problem.

You need two for loops one per object as follows:

```
function JsonMergeCompare(obj1, obj2 ) {

  var renamed_obj2 = JsonRename(obj2);

  var output = {};
  for (i in obj1)
    output[i] = obj1[i];
  for (i in renamed_obj2)
    output[i] = renamed_obj2[i];
  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, I'm sure what is really you want but I just based my answer in your desired output

```js
<script>
//First Array (obj1)
var _obj1=[  
   {  
      "name":"Metric 1",
      "value":33731487,
   },
   {  
      "name":"Metric 2",
      "value":11252893,
   }
];

//Second Array (obj2):
var _obj2=[  
   {  
      "name":"Metric 1",
      "value":118181851,
   },
   {  
      "name":"Metric 2",
      "value":15151,
   },
   {  
      "name":"Metric 3",
      "value":123,
   },

];
 function jsonRename(obj1,obj2){
  var out=[];
  var keys={};
  var ctr=0;
  var indx=0;
  for(v in obj1){
     if(typeof(obj1[v].name)!="undefined" ){
     var n=obj1[v].name;
      if( typeof(keys[n])=="undefined"){
     out.push(obj1[v]);  
     keys[n]=out.length-1;   
      }
      for(v1 in obj2){
     try{
       if(n==obj2[v1].name){
       ctr++;
       out[keys[n]]["name_compare"+ctr]= obj2[v1].name;
       out[keys[n]]["value_compare"+ctr]= obj2[v1].value;
       }
     }catch(e){}
      }
     }
  }
   return out;
 }
var out=jsonRename(_obj1,_obj2);

</script>
```